# Only continue for loop when async get request finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am writing a tool that will loop through a list of id's (represented by id in `id_list`). We check a cache object to see if we already have a value for the id. If we don't already have a value for the given id, we'll need to make a `get` request to get the associated value and then add it to the cache.

In the time it takes to do one `async` get request, the entire loop runs. This means the cache is never actually used. Is there anyway I can require the `get` request to finish before continuing the loop? Normally I would chain the request through the `onSuccess` function of the previous, but since there's a change, no request will be made.

```
cache = {};
var rating;
for (id in id_list){
   if (id in cache){
       rating = cache[id];
   }else{
       rating = $.get(~~~async get request happens here~~~);
       cache[id] = rating;
   }
   $(".result").append(rating);//display result in ui
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `for` loop if you want it to wait between each iteration.  A common design pattern is to create a local function for a given iteration and then call it each time the async operation finishes.

Assuming `id_list` is an object with properties, you could do it like this:

```
var cache = {};
var ids = Object.keys(id_list);
var cntr = 0;
function next() {
    var id;
    if (cntr < ids.length) {
        id = ids[cntr++];
        // see if we can just get the value from the cache
        if (id in cache) {
            $(".result").append(cache[id]);
            // schedule next iteration of the loop
            setTimeout(next, 1);
        } else {
            // otherwise get rating via Ajax call
            $.get(...).then(function(rating) {
                $(".result").append(rating);
                // put rating in the cache
                cache[id] = rating;
                next();
            });
        }
    }
}

next();
```

Or, if `id_list` is an array of ids, you can change it to this:

```
var cache = {};
var cntr = 0;
var id_list = [...];
function next() {
    var id;
    if (cntr < id_list.length) {
        id = id_list[cntr++];
        // see if we can just get the value from the cache
        if (id in cache) {
            $(".result").append(cache[id]);
            // schedule next iteration of the loop
            setTimeout(next, 1);
        } else {
            // otherwise get rating via Ajax call
            $.get(...).then(function(rating) {
                $(".result").append(rating);
                // put rating in the cache
                cache[id] = rating;
                next();
            });
        }
    }
}

next();
```