# NodeJS Waiting for asynchronous function to complete foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Hi so i have been trying to make this tried using async module didn't really know how to convert this to one tried promising it didn't really work well i think i did it wrong so i reverted the function to the way it was at first

Basically i want to wait till the ReadJson() function is done with reading all the json files that are in the array then do other functions like editjson etc

Code:

App.js

```
const Reader = require('./Reader');
Reader.ReadJson();
```

Reader.js

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');
const JsonFiles = ['json1.json', 'json2.json', 'json3.json', 'json4.json'];
const JsonContents = [];
class Reader {
    static ReadJson() {
        JsonFiles.forEach(name => {
            let FileDir = "D:\\Development\\Java\\" + name;
            fsp.readJson(FileDir).then(contents => {
                if (contents) {
                    JsonContents.push(contents);
                    console.log(`Loaded >> ${name} ${Reader.JsonContents.length}/${JsonFiles.length}`);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log('Done Reading Json Content!');
        //Other functions
    }
}
Reader.JsonContents = JsonContents;
module.exports = Reader;
```

So basically the output is:

```
Done Reading Json Content!
Loaded >> json1.json 1/4
Loaded >> json2.json 2/4
Loaded >> json3.json 3/4
Loaded >> json4.json 4/4
```

When i need it to be:

```
Loaded >> json1.json 1/4
Loaded >> json2.json 2/4
Loaded >> json3.json 3/4
Loaded >> json4.json 4/4
Done Reading Json Content!
```

Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983138/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed ?

Comment: There are dozens of questions with more than dozens of answers here already on stackoverflow about how to sequence a loop of async operations like you have.  I'd suggest you find those and learn from them.

Comment: One solution: [Only continue for loop when async get request finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662425/only-continue-for-loop-when-async-get-request-finishes/33662492#33662492)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a promise, track your progress in the `forEach` and resolve it only when `JsonContents` length is the same as `JsonFiles` length.

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');
const JsonFiles = ['json1.json', 'json2.json', 'json3.json', 'json4.json'];
const JsonContents = [];
class Reader {
    static ReadJson() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            JsonFiles.forEach(name => {
                let FileDir = "D:\\Development\\Java\\" + name;
                fsp.readJson(FileDir).then(contents => {
                    if (contents) {
                        JsonContents.push(contents);
                        console.log(`Loaded >> ${name} ${Reader.JsonContents.length}/${JsonFiles.length}`);
                    }
                    if (JsonContents.length == JsonFile.length) {
                        return resolve(JsonContents);
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    return reject(err);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
Reader.JsonContents = JsonContents;
module.exports = Reader;
```

And then use it in your app:

```
const Reader = require('./Reader');
Reader.ReadJson().then(() => { console.log('Done Reading Json Content!'); });
```

Another option is using `Promise.all`, because you are using `fs-promise`, but although it can be done with `forEach`, a regular `for` loop is better here.

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');
const JsonFiles = ['json1.json', 'json2.json', 'json3.json', 'json4.json'];
const JsonContents = [];
class Reader {
    static ReadJson() {
        var promises = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < JsonFiles.length; i++) {
            let FileDir = "D:\\Development\\Java\\" + JsonFiles[i];
            promises.push(fsp.readJson(FileDir).then(contents => {
                if (contents) {
                    JsonContents.push(contents);
                    console.log(`Loaded >> ${JsonFiles[i]} ${Reader.JsonContents.length}/${JsonFiles.length}`);
                }
            }));

        }
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
}
Reader.JsonContents = JsonContents;
module.exports = Reader;
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern to create a wrapper promise when `fsp.readJson()` already makes promises.  You can just chain those promises if you want sequential operation.

Comment: @jfriend00 That is the purpose of `Promise.all` example, and also there is a recursive promise option that I did not mentioned so it won't be "over complicated" solution.

Comment: Do you understand what the [promise anti-patterns are](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)?  You can sequence your first code block and still not wrap in a newly created promise by using the promise returned form `fsp.readJson()` more intelligently.  Doing so would also have other benefits, like it would stop looping when it got an error rather than continue through the whole rest of the loop like your solution does.

Comment: I accept your comment, but can not see how you can do it without recursion. If it can be done, I would love to see and learn how

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [Ron Dadon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4908482/ron-dadon) Promise.all method....

The [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) promise library provides some helper functions like [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/map.html) and [`Promise.filter`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html) that can remove a lot of the boiler plate of Promise array processing code.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fsp = require('fs-promise');
const path = require('path');


class Reader {

  static readFiles(jsonPath, jsonFiles){
    let fileReadCount = 0;
    return Promise.map(jsonFiles, name => {
        let filePath = path.join(jsonPath, name);
        return fsp.readJson(filePath);
      })
      .filter((content, index, length) => {
        if (!content) return false;
        console.log(`Loaded >> ${jsonFiles[index]} ${index+1} / ${length}`);
        return true;
      })
  }

  static readJson() {
    return this.readFiles(this.jsonPath, this.jsonFiles).then(contents => {
      console.log('Done Reading Json Content!', contents);
      return this.jsonContents = contents;
    })
  }

}

Reader.jsonFiles = ['json1.json', 'json2.json', 'json3.json', 'json4.json'];
Reader.jsonPath = 'D:\\Development\\Java';

module.exports = Reader;
```